# Why can't I see merged results pipeline options

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I was looking at GitLab Docs, specifically to CI/CD part, and I found interesting the part say it's possible to trigger a pipeline to a result of merge request. It would be very nice to trigger deploys jobs after merge to main branch, but what happens is that I can't found the checkbox they indicates at docs (above the steps)

```
To enable merged results pipelines in a project, you must have at least the Maintainer role:

1. On the top bar, select Menu > Projects and find your project.
2. On the left sidebar, select Settings > General.
3. Expand Merge requests.
4. Select Enable merged results pipelines.
5. Select Save changes.
```

And above is what I see in **Settings/General/Merge Requests**
[merge options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIC0T.png)

I don't know if its is a problem, but my gitlab is a private instance, in 15.3 version. Thinking that this could be the problem I sign up to gitlab.com and created a new project. Same thing happened there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merged results pipelines are a feature of GitLab **premium**. You must have a valid premium (or higher) subscription or license entitlement in order to use this feature. If you don't see the feature on a project you own/maintain, it means that your subscription does not have this feature.

Comment: OMG Why they does not put it in docs.... it has a pre requisits session, I believe this is a huge pre requite so.... Well, any Ideia in how to use a `rules` field so pipeline runs on merge request and in results of these merges? But no for any commit/push

Comment: @DaniloMourelle it's subtle, but if you look at the documentation you linked, it says "premium" next to the headline. Check out the docs for the `workflow:rules:` there are examples (and built in templates you can include) to do MR-only or branch-only setups. However, none of these will check the _merged result_ without the Premium feature.

Comment: I found it later.... It's in red but small sized next to a title with much bigger size.... Thank you...